# Suppose $|\alpha + \beta| \le |\alpha' +\beta'|$. Is it then possible that $|\alpha'| + |\beta'| \le |\alpha| + |\beta|$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\alpha, \beta, \alpha', \beta'  \in \mathbb C$ and that $|\alpha + \beta| \le |\alpha' +\beta'|$.

By using the triangle inequality is it then possible that $|\alpha'| + |\beta'| \le |\alpha| + |\beta|$?

I've been looking for a counter example, since I've no luck in proving this.

Comment: The two inequalities are unrelated. $\lvert -300 + 300 \rvert \le \lvert -1 + 0 \rvert$ and $\lvert 1 + 1 \rvert \le \lvert 2 + 2 \rvert$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible both ways. For your statement to hold, take $\alpha = 4$, $\beta = -4$, $\alpha' = \beta' = 1$. For your statement to not hold, take $\alpha = \beta = 0$ and $\alpha' = \beta' = 1$. So your statement doesn't even hold in the reals.